# Accommodate for eventual NULL value in Reactive Form PatchValue in Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, patch

I have a form with the capacity to delete an image from it when updating. I am using Reactive Forms in Angular 8. I use PatchValue to show existing data from the API like this:

```
editArticle(article: Article) {
    this.articleEdit.patchValue(
      {
        feed_type: article.feed_type.data.id,
        title: article.title,
        sub_title: article.sub_title,
        description: article.description,
        text_content: article.text_content,
        author_name: article.author_name,
        author_avatar: article.author_avatar.data,
        video_url: article.video_url,
        header_image: article.header_image.data,<-- this is the issue BTW
        featured_image: article.featured_image.data,
        twitter: article.twitter,
        facebook: article.facebook,
        instagram: article.instagram,
        advertising_banner: article.advertising_banner.data,
        ad_link: article.ad_link
      }
    );
  }
```

When I do this **(UPDATED CODE)**:

```
deleteHeaderImage(article: Article) {
this.startLoading();
let updatedArticle = {
  header_image: {
    id: null
  }
}
this.articleService.updateArticleById(this.id, updatedArticle)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response) {
        this.article = response.data;
        this.articleEdit.patchValue({
          header_image: null
        })
        this.stopLoading();
      }
    }
  )
```

}

Setting a patchValue on the response removes the error, but when I refresh the page, the image is gone which is great, but the error returns in the console and reverts back to the original patchValue object in editArticle()

the form is updated successfully and the image is deleted, but I then get an error of:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null
```

after response.data

On inspection, this relates to the fact that the patchValue in the above editArticle() method is looking for **article.header_image.data**

I've been thinking that this was something do with the .html file and ensuring that there are safeguards to check if null value returns, but it seems that it is down to the above. I'm not sure what to do. Did anyone work this out in the past? I'm a little stuck.

Comment: you can separate patching header image data and the rest. check the header image if it is not null patch the value or make an inline conditional assignment like `header_image: article.header_image ? article.header_image.data : null`

Comment: in the same object? That looks like a nifty technique. Thank you Eldar, I shall give this a try. I was trying out || but that wasn't making a difference. I didn't know you could run checks like that.

Comment: smashing thank you. worked a treat.